# How do I permanently save images to device without syncing outside of device - SWIFTUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, file-manager

In a previous question, I was able to get working saving images to Documents. I guess I misunderstood how that worked as when the app gets deleted, all the images saved to documents also get deleted. Is there a way to save images to the device, so that if the app was deleted and reinstalled, those images would still be accessible?

Background:

I have an app that keeps track of a collection of items for the user. The user base is a private bunch, and I know that they would not want the collection saved to the cloud to be synced that way. So my goal is to export the data to a csv that they can save and reimport if needed. One of the attributes is a picture. You cannot export pictures to a csv so instead I saved them to documents using file manager. But, on app deletion, that data gets deleted as well. Is there a way to export the photos permanently, so that even if they deleted the app, but later reinstalled and then imported the csv, that the images would still be there?

Comment: You can use [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) to allow users to save files outside of your app sandbox or enable `UIFileSharingEnabled` so that your app's documents folder is available from the files app. Users can then backup and restore data using the files app

Comment: You might want to look at [document packages](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html). By the way, none of this is SwiftUI-specific. SwiftUI is a framework for displaying the UI on screen (and potentially the lifecycle of the app) but won't affect your document storage choices.

Comment: So I enabled UIFileSharingEnabled and got that working where I can see the documents folder in the Files app. The problem still remains that when I delete the app, it deletes that folder. Is there a way to keep that folder even after deleting the app?

Comment: No.  That document folder is part of your app's sandbox. When you delete the app, the folder goes too. That's just the way it is. By exposing your documents folder you make it easier for your users to copy their data somewhere else and copy it back later

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.